# Replacing keyboard with picker view when textfield is tapped (Swift, Storyboard, iOS 9, Xcode 7)

Tags: swift, xcode7, uipickerview, uitableview

I can't seem to find how I could replace the keyboard when I tap a textfield in the following context:

I have a view controller with a tableview dragged into it with one prototype cell, and in that cell I have 4 textfields. As for my swift files, I have one for the table view (view controller) and one for the cell itself.

I was able to replace the keyboard with a datepicker for one textfield, but do not know how to proceed for a picker view...

Thank you in advance for any help/advice given! Please let me know if you need more detail.

Cheers,

Laroms

Comment: you can use the library and you just need a label: https://github.com/hijamoya/PickerViewCell

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you are asking to change the input type of the `UITextField`.

You can make use of `inputView` property of the UITextField. Set the `inputView` for the required `textField` as `UIPickerView`. It'll automatically change the input type.

Comment: Much appreciated, Varun - can I just ask if any part of my code should go in the view controller file with the tableview and in the tableview cell file?

Comment: You can set the input view for the necessary textField in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.